# How do I disable form resizing for users?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, resize

How do I disable form resizing for users? Which property is used?

I tried `AutoSize` and `AutoSizeMode`.

Answer (score 267):

Change the `FormBorderStyle` to one of the fixed values: `FixedSingle`, `Fixed3D`,
`FixedDialog` or `FixedToolWindow`.

The `FormBorderStyle` property is under the *Appearance* category.

Or check this:

```
// Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
form1.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

// Set the MaximizeBox to false to remove the maximize box.
form1.MaximizeBox = false;

// Set the MinimizeBox to false to remove the minimize box.
form1.MinimizeBox = false;

// Set the start position of the form to the center of the screen.
form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

// Display the form as a modal dialog box.
form1.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 51):

Use the `FormBorderStyle` property. Make it `FixedSingle`:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

Answer (score 17):

Use the `FormBorderStyle` property of your `Form`:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

Answer (score 9):

Change this property and try this at design time:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
```

Designer view before the change:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I always use this:

```
// Lock form
this.MaximumSize = this.Size;
this.MinimumSize = this.Size;
```

This way you can always resize the form from Designer without changing code.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `MaximumSize` and `MinimumSize` properties of the form will fix the form size, and prevent the user from resizing the form, while keeping the form default `FormBorderStyle`.

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(XX, YY);
this.MinimumSize = new Size(X, Y);
```

Comment: For no resizing, wouldn't this.MaximumSize = new Size(XX, YY); this.MinimumSize = this.MaximumSize also do the trick?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the mouse cursor will still change to resize arrows when it's over the window border. Changing the FormBorderStyle means you get the right mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the maximum size, minimum size and remove the gripper icon of the window.

Set properties (MaximumSize, MinimumSize, and SizeGripStyle):

```
this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 550);
this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 550);
this.SizeGripStyle = System.Windows.Forms.SizeGripStyle.Hide;
```